Qt.ItemIsTristate missing in PySide6?
I'm porting some code from PySide2 to PySide6 and have problems with the Qt.ItemIsTristate flag for a QTreeWidget item. Seems like this flag is missing in PySide6? Any suggestions how to work around this? I haven't found any info in the docs.
qtreewidgetitem.setFlags(master.flags() | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsTristate | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable)
# Works:
from PySide2 import QtCore
print(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsTristate)

# Does not work:
from PySide6 import QtCore
print(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsTristate)


Looks like it's changed name to ItemIsAutoTristate.

If you checked the related ItemFlag documentation you'd have seen that there's no ItemIsTristate (it was already deprecated even in later Qt versions). Use ItemIsAutoTristate or ItemIsUserTristate. You should also prefer the full syntax for all enums (eg: Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsAutoTristate), which is mandatory since PyQt6 and may become as such sooner on later in PySide too.

Thanks a lot! Somehow I missed this when searching.
